# SQL Alchemy join statement

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble converting this SQL query into a SQL Alchemy query:

```
query = """
            SELECT i.case_num,
                    to_char(i.date_time, 'FMMonth FMDD, YYYY'),
                    to_char(i.date_time, 'HH24:MI'),
                    i.incident_type, 
                    i.incident_cat, 
                    i.injury, 
                    i.property_damage,
                    i.description,
                    i.root_cause,
                    a.corrective_action,
                    a.due_date,
                    i.user_id
                FROM incident as i, action_items as a
                WHERE i.case_num = a.case_id AND i.case_num = %s;
            """
```

I have tried the following but have received nothing but errors:

sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound: No row was found for one()

```
results = dbsession.query(Incidents.case_num,
                                    func.to_char(Incidents.date_time, 'FMMonth FMDD, YYYY'),
                                    func.to_char(Incidents.date_time, 'HH24:MI'),
                                    Incidents.incident_type,
                                    Incidents.incident_cat,
                                    Incidents.injury,
                                    Incidents.property_damage,
                                    Incidents.description,
                                    Incidents.root_cause,
                                    Actions.corrective_action,
                                    Actions.due_date,

Incidents.user_id).join(Actions).filter_by(case_id = id).one()
```

AttributeError: mapper

```
results = dbsession.query(Incidents.case_num,
                                func.to_char(Incidents.date_time, 'FMMonth FMDD, YYYY'),
                                func.to_char(Incidents.date_time, 'HH24:MI'),
                                Incidents.incident_type,
                                Incidents.incident_cat,
                                Incidents.injury,
                                Incidents.property_damage,
                                Incidents.description,
                                Incidents.root_cause,
                                Incidents.user_id).join(Actions.corrective_action, Actions.due_date).filter_by(case_id = id).one()
```

I figure I can do two separate queries but would rather figure out how to perform one join query instead.

Comment: What is showed when you print string representation of your query (let's say, first one)?

Comment: Nothing, so I don't believe the query is properly formatted.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing? Does printing is interrupted by some exception or result is empty string?

Comment: Nothing is printed, so it I believe it must be interrupted by the exception.

Comment: When I changed .one() to .all() it did print an empty string.

Comment: Try to print query instead of object/list - which means, don't use one/all methods on query and print it's string representation: `print(str(result))`.

Comment: It prints out the SQL query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153886/discussion-between-erhesto-and-jtp709).

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't need to specify a join explicitly to get sqlalchemy to generate the statment you want.

Also, (my opinion). Avoid using filter_by.

In this case filter_by is not smart enough to realize that `id` is a column in `Incidents`, because `id` is a built in function. `filter_by` [(see source)](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L1544)
accepts where conditions as keyword arguments, unpacks them, treating the keys as columns to be looked up, *but not the values*, then it calls the `filter` method with all the conditions conjoined.

relevant bit of code:

```
def filter_by(self, **kwargs):
    clauses = [_entity_descriptor(self._joinpoint_zero(), key) == value
               for key, value in kwargs.items()]
    return self.filter(sql.and_(*clauses))
```

*if `id` were provided as a left-hand value, i.e.*

```
stmt = dbsession.query(...).join(...).filter_by(id = 123)
```

*The statement would compile. However, the following would not compile*

```
stmt = dbsession.query(...).join(...).filter_by(id = case_id)
```

*because, `case_id` is not a variable in scope*

*And, the OP's version*

```
stmt = dbsession.query(...).join(...).filter_by(case_id = id)
```

can resolve `case_id` properly, and sees that there is something in the current scope named `id` (the built-in), and tries to use it

This *should* do what you want:

```
results = dbsession.query(
  Incidents.case_num,
  func.to_char(Incidents.date_time, 'FMMonth FMDD, YYYY'),
  func.to_char(Incidents.date_time, 'HH24:MI'),
  Incidents.incident_type,
  Incidents.incident_cat,
  Incidents.injury,
  Incidents.property_damage,
  Incidents.description,
  Incidents.root_cause,
  Actions.corrective_action,
  Actions.due_date,
  Incidents.user_id).filter(
    Actions.case_id == Incidents.id
).filter(
    Incidents.case_num == 123
).one() 
# ^ here's how one would add multiple filters to a query
```

FYI, you can save `query` objects and inspect them, like this:

```
stmt = dbsession.query(...).filter(...)
print(stmt)
```

And then fetch the results with

```
stmt.one()
# or stmt.first() or stmt.all() or ...
```

Comment: While I share your sentiment that the more explicit `filter()` is nicer in many situations, the reasoning here is not sound. The provided example fails to show what `id` even is in their case. It could be the builtin function even, as you've guessed. To say that "`filter_by` is not smart enough to realize that `id` is a column in `Incidents`" is potentially asking it to do the impossible. Instead it'd help to explain how `filter_by()` actually works.

Comment: Thanks @IljaEverilä, as soon as I get a chance I'll update my answer explaining how `filter_by` works. I think it has something to do with variadic args but I have to look at the source before I update my answer.

Comment: [The docs are actually pretty decent on this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by). `filter_by()` uses the given keyword args, and "The keyword expressions are extracted from the primary entity of the query, or the last entity that was the target of a call to `Query.join()`." So given that the primary entity, or a previous target to a join, was X, a `filter_by(y=z)` is equivalent to `filter(X.y == z)` (+ `and_`ing different criteria etc.). And again, I also actually prefer `filter()` most of the time.

Comment: thanks, i looked at the source and updated my answer accordingly. appreciate the feedback as this is visible to all future readers